# How to change script dir inside a function?

Tags: bash

I try to change the directory inside a bash-script function, but it does not have any effect. Possibly, because the function is run inside a separate process...

Here is a simple script without a function call. It works perfectly:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Doing it without the function works:
echo "Dir: $PWD" # Output: "/Users/philipp/"
cd ~/Documents
echo "Dir: $PWD" # Output: "/Users/philipp/Documents"
```

However, once I move the `cd` into a function, it does not change the directory for the rest of the shell script anymore:

```
#!/bin/bash

show_or_run() {
    if [[ "yes" = $RUN ]]; then
        eval "$@"
    else
        echo "   $ $@"
    fi
}

echo "Dir: $PWD" # Output: "/Users/philipp/"
show_or_run cd ~/Documents
echo "Dir: $PWD" # Output: "/Users/philipp/", but expected "/Users/philipp/Documents"
```

Comment: Hmm is `RUN` set as an environment variable in the outer scope. Where is it defined? If it isn't defined then you don't change directory.

Comment: oh!! You are right @AttRigh... I actually did not set the `RUN` variable

Comment: Cool cool. Because of this the question seems kind of specific - so I would be in favour of closing it... unless someone told me a good reason for leaving it around - not that this is something I have the power to do :). I guess knowing about "eval cd blah" is interesting...  I'm not sure this question is the best way to index this fact thought